# Idiomatic way of counting number of related objects

Tags: django

This is how I am doing it currently:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    ...

    def nr_notes(self):
        return len(Note.objects.filter(article=self.pk))


class Note(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But I thought "there must be a better way". Probably accessing [the generated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) `notes_set` field?

What is the right way to implement the method `nr_notes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count), this does a count query on the database rather than evaluating the filter

```
 Note.objects.filter(article=self.pk).count()
```

From [evaluating querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you might expect, returns the length of the result list.
>
> Note: If you only need to determine the number of records in the set (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s much more efficient to handle a count at the database level using SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*). Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

Comment: Thanks! What about using the generated `notes_set` field? Is that possible?

Comment: @delavnog - `notes_set` is still just a queryset so yes `self.notes_set.count()` will still work

Comment: Thanks, lifesaver! The reason I need this is to avoid dependency cycles with my customized user model: some of my models need the user, and my user model would need to import the other models to do the model-based query, which would cause problems.

Comment: @delavnog - No worries, that sounds like a separate issue you'd need to look into but it sounds like it could be avoided by `.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

Comment: I already use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. And using `notes_set` gets rid of the dependency cycle, so problem solved, thanks!